# How to call the Django-Admin style of providing much with less code

Tags: django, django-admin, terminology

I like the django admin very much.

You only need to configure it. Making the admin site available for some models hardly "software development".

I would call it "from coding to configuring". But that's not a term.

How is the general term? A well-known term which has an explanation at wikipedia or in a book would be nice.

I tried [Scaffolding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29), but I think this is not the right term, since no code gets generated.

Comment: I don't think its a style just a reusable app (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/reusable-apps/) in the context of Django. Or maybe in terms of other applications plugins/modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One might call such approach a "**Parameterized Programming**".

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2283189

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion it's just good OOP design combined with a good meta-programming design.

First, a `Model` defines what is possible and how one should achieve that. Having this structured way of thinking about models enables one to create a set of base classes to represent common actions on said objects.

Combined with another set of good base classes in the form of Django viewsets allows one to translate all this to HTTP.

Please note the admin matured on the course of almost (over?) a decade now. In 2009 there was **a lot** more of boilerplate needed. It was "just" a process of removing it.

---

Please note the [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) takes this idea and expands it so good that all of CRUD API design can be called "coding by configuration".

Comment: "coding by configuration" that term matches. Thank you. Unfortunately if I search for "coding by configuration" I mostly get results for "Convention over configuration".

Comment: @guettli "Parameterized Programming"? https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2283189

Comment: "Parameterized Programming" sounds like a valid answer. Please write it as answer, then I can up-vote it.

Answer (score 3):

Something that you see so rarely, it doesn't have a generic term?

I'd call it extreme general-purpose coding. Something that tries to be as generally useful as possible, so a thousand users with a thousand disparate applications don't have to write a thousand different codes. Instead, they just declare what they want.

Every programmer sooner or later learns that you never do `price = list_price * 0.9`, you do `price =  list_price * (( 100.0 - DISCOUNT_PERCENT) / 100.0 )`, and that at a later date you'll be querying DISCOUNT_PERCENT out of the database  based on the customer ... Django-admin is that approach taken to the N'th degree.

[Edit]

Can't think how you get to a generic noun phrase  from here, but Django's own slogan is worth mentioning in this context.

Django -- the web framework *for perfectionists with deadlines*.

[Edit 2]

"Metaprogramming done right "?

Comment: And then you don't want to write it anymore and you start using a library. https://github.com/mirumee/prices

Comment: Yes, Django-admin has a lot in common with a well-written library, except it's rather more ... amorphous? Less self-contained?

Comment: I meant https://github.com/mirumee/prices as a library for your example with the discount. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

How about WYSIWYG? I know it's not strictly correct as this isn't a graphical display. But based on your question of configuration over coding. It's very similar in that with WYSIWYG you only select what you want rather than write code for it.

As other comments and answers have provided, there seems to be no one term for this. I agree completely with Krzysztof's answer too. I think the correct answer is not established here, but instead is a mix of ideas.

I think in essence it comes down to quite simply "Good Design"!

Comment: According to wikipedia "WYSIWYG implies a user interface that allows the user to view something very similar to the end result—while the document is being created." I think WYSIWYG does not match here. And "Good Design" is a bit vague.